# How to perform a running sum on values that resets on null values

Tags: postgresql, sum, window-functions, date-range, date-arithmetic

I am trying to calculate sum of delay days (PostgreSQL), but the running sum  will reset upon null values.

I have tried it using window function:

```
sum(delay_days)
       over (partition by id, status order by id, upper_range_effective_date asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)  as delay_days_sum
```

but I did not get the right result.

Here is my table:

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table(
          id INT,
          status varchar,
          lower_range_effective_date date,
          upper_range_effective_date date ,
          delay_days int -- if null then lower_range_effective_date is payment date
        );



INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES
    (1, 'failed', '2019-11-06', '2019-12-05 ',29);
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES
    (1, 'failed', '2019-12-05', '2019-12-16 ',11);

......

INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES
    (1, 'completed', '2020-04-10', '2020-05-05 ',NULL);
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES
    (1, 'failed', '2020-05-05', '2020-06-05 ',31);
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES
    (1, 'failed', '2020-06-05', '2020-07-05 ',30);
```

using window function:

```
 select *, sum(delay_days)
           over (partition by id, status order by id, lower_range_effective_date asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)  as delay_days_sum from temp_table
    order by lower_range_effective_date;
```

For example if I had a dataset like this:

```
id  |status    | lower_range_effective_date | upper_range_effective_date| delay_days
----+----------+----------------------------+---------------------------+--------------
1   |failed    | 2019-11-06                 | 2019-12-05                | 29
1   |failed    | 2019-12-05                 | 2019-12-16                | 11
1   |completed | 2019-12-16                 | 2020-01-06                | <null>
1   |failed    | 2020-01-06                 | 2020-01-08                | 2
1   |completed | 2020-01-08                 | 2020-02-05                | <null>
1   |failed    | 2020-02-05                 | 2020-02-07                | 2
1   |completed | 2020-02-07                 | 2020-03-05                | <null>
1   |failed    | 2020-03-05                 | 2020-03-19                | 14
1   |completed | 2020-03-19                 | 2020-04-06                | <null>
1   |failed    | 2020-04-06                 | 2020-04-10                | 4
1   |completed | 2020-04-10                 | 2020-05-05                | <null>
1   |failed    | 2020-05-05                 | 2020-06-05                | 31
1   |failed    | 2020-06-05                 | 2020-07-05                | 30
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
id  |status    | lower_range_effective_date | upper_range_effective_date| delay_days     | delay_days_sum
----+----------+----------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+----------------- 
1   |failed    | 2019-11-06                 | 2019-12-05                | 29             |29
1   |failed    | 2019-12-05                 | 2019-12-16                | 11             |40
1   |completed | 2019-12-16                 | 2020-01-06                | <null>         |<null> 
1   |failed    | 2020-01-06                 | 2020-01-08                | 2              |2
1   |completed | 2020-01-08                 | 2020-02-05                | <null>         |<null> 
1   |failed    | 2020-02-05                 | 2020-02-07                | 2              |2
1   |completed | 2020-02-07                 | 2020-03-05                | <null>         |<null> 
1   |failed    | 2020-03-05                 | 2020-03-19                | 14             | 14
1   |completed | 2020-03-19                 | 2020-04-06                | <null>         | <null>
1   |failed    | 2020-04-06                 | 2020-04-10                | 4              | 4 
1   |completed | 2020-04-10                 | 2020-05-05                | <null>         | <null>
1   |failed    | 2020-05-05                 | 2020-06-05                | 31             | 31
1   |failed    | 2020-06-05                 | 2020-07-05                | 30             | 61
```

Answer (score 1):

Made a table similar to your:

```
 id |     upper_date      | delay_days
----+---------------------+------------
  1 | 2019-12-05 00:00:00 |         29
  1 | 2019-12-16 00:00:00 |         11
  1 | 2020-01-06 00:00:00 |
  1 | 2020-01-08 00:00:00 |          2
  1 | 2020-02-05 00:00:00 |
  1 | 2020-02-07 00:00:00 |          2
  1 | 2020-03-05 00:00:00 |
  1 | 2020-03-19 00:00:00 |         14
  1 | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |
  1 | 2020-04-10 00:00:00 |          4
  1 | 2020-05-05 00:00:00 |
  1 | 2020-06-05 00:00:00 |         31
  1 | 2020-07-05 00:00:00 |         30
```

The idea is the following. Create an auxiliary column `"case"`, where the values will be 1 if `"delay_days" = NULL` and the rest 0. Then in the next `subquery`, the `cumulative sum` of `"case"` is considered and written to the `"total"` column. When completed, the selection is `grouped by "total"` and the cumulative amounts by groups are calculated.

```
SELECT *, SUM("delay_days") OVER (PARTITION BY total ORDER BY id, upper_date asc)
FROM 
(SELECT *, SUM("case") OVER (ORDER BY id, upper_date asc) as total
FROM 
(
 SELECT *,
 CASE WHEN "delay_days" IS NULL THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END
 FROM aaa
)
pseudo1
)
pseudo2
;
```

Output

```
 id |     upper_date      | delay_days | case | total | sum
----+---------------------+------------+------+-------+-----
  1 | 2019-12-05 00:00:00 |         29 |    0 |     0 |  29
  1 | 2019-12-16 00:00:00 |         11 |    0 |     0 |  40
  1 | 2020-01-06 00:00:00 |            |    1 |     1 |
  1 | 2020-01-08 00:00:00 |          2 |    0 |     1 |   2
  1 | 2020-02-05 00:00:00 |            |    1 |     2 |
  1 | 2020-02-07 00:00:00 |          2 |    0 |     2 |   2
  1 | 2020-03-05 00:00:00 |            |    1 |     3 |
  1 | 2020-03-19 00:00:00 |         14 |    0 |     3 |  14
  1 | 2020-04-06 00:00:00 |            |    1 |     4 |
  1 | 2020-04-10 00:00:00 |          4 |    0 |     4 |   4
  1 | 2020-05-05 00:00:00 |            |    1 |     5 |
  1 | 2020-06-05 00:00:00 |         31 |    0 |     5 |  31
  1 | 2020-07-05 00:00:00 |         30 |    0 |     5 |  61
```

Just in case, this is how the table was created:

```
CREATE TABLE "aaa" (
        "id" INTEGER,
        "upper_date" TIMESTAMP,
    "delay_days"    INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO "aaa" ("id", "upper_date", "delay_days") VALUES 
 (1, '2019-12-05', 29),
 (1, '2019-12-16', 11),
 (1, '2020-01-06', NULL),
 (1, '2020-01-08', 2),
 (1, '2020-02-05', NULL),
 (1, '2020-02-07', 2),
 (1, '2020-03-05', NULL),
 (1, '2020-03-19', 14),
 (1, '2020-04-06', NULL),
 (1, '2020-04-10', 4),
 (1, '2020-05-05', NULL),
 (1, '2020-06-05', 31),
 (1, '2020-07-05', 30);
```